# "Solicit" vs. "elicit"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Looking for general information with regards to *solicit* vs *elicit*, as well as which would be the correct word for this phrase:

> Before spending time learning your system, I just wanted to [solicit
>   or elicit] some feedback from you.

Some background:

A person had written an advertisement basically for their system, and I asked a question and then wrote the above phrase using `solicit`

I've seen both *elicit* and *solicit* used almost interchangeably in this kind of phrasing about getting feedback.  I've also read that *elicit* should be used if it is a process and/or it doesn't necessarily benefit the person.  There is definitely some confusion on my part with regards to the use of those two words in this example.

Comment: Does a dictionary help? [Elicit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elicit) | [Solicit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solicit) Using those definitions, is there anything still unclear?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Both definitions seem to apply which is why I asked the question.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're not sure, what's wrong with "ask for".

Comment: @TrevorD there is nothing wrong with "ask for"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is perhaps best illustrated by the fact that you can [*elicit the truth from the evidence*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22elicit%20the%20truth%20from%20the%20evidence%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but not *solicit* (*soliciting* is *asking*, implying a "conscious" entity you're seeking something from). Relevant definitions from OED...

> **elicit** - to bring out, educe (principles, truths, etc.) *from* the data in which they are implied.
>   Also, to extract, draw out (information) *from* a person by interrogation; sometimes with object clause introduced by *that*.
>
> **solicit** - to seek after; to try to find, obtain, or acquire.

As implied by the *second* part of the first definition, in OP's exact context either word could be used. And I would say the intended meaning is so clear it's pointless to suggest the actual choice of verb could have any semantic significance there (most people would just use *get* or *ask for* anyway).

---

That OED definition implies that when you ***elicit*** information from **a person**, you're treating him *insensitively, inhumanely*. The other two current answers say it's when you get information out of someone [*surreptitiously*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surreptitious) or *indirectly*.

I think all these implications arise naturally from the fact that you normally ***elicit*** information from **data/things**. If it's *from a **person***, you've effectively "objectified" him, which can lead to a range of negative connotations (but none universally observed).

---

Note that there's a much clearer and more consistent distinction between the two words in, say,...

> 1: We will solicit feedback from the users
>    2: We will elicit feedback from the users

In #1 we're going to *ask*, but we *might not get* the feedback. In #2 we're saying we *will* get it (by force if necessary! :).

Comment: 'in OP's exact context either word could be used.' But with different meanings, surely. As you point out with the 'torture to elicit information' usage statistic. I certainly would react badly to someone saying they intended to elicit information from me.

Comment: @Bobbi Bennett: I don't think *"by interrogation"* in the OED definition necessarily implies the Spanish Inquisition! :) Anyway, here are over 1000 [elicit your comments](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22elicit+your+comments%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) which I think isn't likely to occur very often at all in "coercive" contexts.

Comment: Well, 900 of those guys probably meant solicit and didn't know it (grin). Hopefully the next 1000 will come by here, and find the right word for their meaning!

Comment: @Bobbi: Possibly. It's true that *in toto* there are about [15 *solicit your comments* for every *elicit your comments*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solicit+your+comments&year_start=1940&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), but if you look at that chart you'll see the "right word" has massively fallen out of favour in the past 2-3 decades. I'd guess that's because of its connotations of *prostitution*, which I don't expect to go away any time soon (so don't get your hopes up re "right will out"! :)

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to [solicit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solicit) some feedback from you:

I just wanted to *ask for* some feedback from you.

vs

I just wanted to [elicit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elicit) some feedback from you:

I just wanted to *[evoke](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evoke), do something that might cause you to provide* some feedback. Perhaps, if I wanted you to smile, in order to elicit that reaction from you, I might tell a joke, or make a funny face.

vs (finally)

I wanted some feedback from you:

What you really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think both terms speak of gaining information, but elicit carries a sense of trying to come by information without making it obvious what you are doing or what information you are really seeking, while solicit is just a straightforward request.

Comment: Sounds correct to me.

Comment: @user48193 thanks for the answer.  Would you say that considering I asked a question for which I was wanting feedback, that solicit is correct in my example?

Comment: Yes, if you're not going about things in a roundabout manner, and are just asking for information directly, then solicit is your word. Elicit is when you may be trying to draw a compliment from someone say, without trying to make it obvious what you are doing, or trying to get someone to incriminate themselves.

Comment: -1 I think 530 written instances of [torture to elicit information](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22torture+to+elicit+information%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) give the lie to this assertion.